Is a New York Durable Power of Attorney Valid in New Jersey?
Have a durable power of attorney signed and notarized in NY for a real estate transaction.  Also, have a property being sold in NJ.  Will I need a second notarized power of attorney in NJ or will my NY power of attorney be sufficient?

The NY power of attorney should be sufficient. A power of attorney does not have to be executed in the place where it is used.

Unless the power of attorney is literally specific to "a real estate transaction" and the transaction taking place in New Jersey isn't the transaction to which the power of attorney applies, no?

@phoog Sure. It would depend upon how specific the language was. If it said "for the limited purpose of the sale of the Empire State Building" it couldn't be used in the NJ deal.
